# Chan of chars to chan of words

Tags: clojure

How can I make a words chan out of chars chan?

I have chan c that read all characters from file. And i need words(str) chan from c chan.(
words need to be made from с, not from a file)

```
  (def file-as-str (slurp "src/clojure2/text.txt"))
    (def read (str/split file-as-str #""))

(defn ch
  [c]
  (go
    (doseq [o read]
      (>! c o)
      ))
  )

(defn word
  [c]
  (let [k (chan)]
    (go-loop []
      (let [o (<! c)]
        (when (not= " " o)
          (>! k o)
          (recur))))
    k))

(defn -main
  [& args]

  (let [c (chan)
        words (chan)]

    ;(go-loop []
    ;  (let [o (<! c)]
    ;    (println o))
    ;  (recur))

    (ch c)
    (word c)
    )
  )
```

**UPDATE**
And so I made a function that returns a chan of characters for 1 word. But I don’t understand how to combine this into 1 word

Comment: If the `word` function should produce the channel of words, then you need to think about a couple of trouble spots:  (1) "when WHAT isn't a space?" and (2) is the first space on the characters channel really the right exit condition for the `word` function?  P.S. Always use the REPL to try out the small forms before embedding them in bigger puzzles. You would have caught the `(= (" "))` right away, before the async channel made it seem complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `chan` with transducer which converts incoming characters to outgoing words.

```clj
  (let [ch (async/chan 100 (comp
                             (partition-by (complement #{\space}))
                             (map #(apply str %))
                             (remove #{" "})))]
    (doseq [c "Hello, world! "]
      (async/>!! ch c))

    (async/<!! (async/into [] (async/take 2 ch))))

=> ["Hello," "world!"]
```

Comment: You can put input from existing source chan using `pipe`:
```(async/pipe ch source-ch)```
where `ch` is your chan with transducer.